# LINQ to SQL optional Column

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I need a functionality to have optional columns in a LINQ to SQL definition. So that LINQ to SQL normally ignores this column within selects and updates etc.
But if a select contains a value for this column it should use this value.

Long version:

### The Scenario

I've the following tables:
[image]

If Field.FieldViews.Count() greater than 0 than should this field be visible.

#### The Problem

If I check the visibility as mentioned above with:

```
Field.FieldViews.Count()
```

Than it makes a single query to the database for every field.
So in my project sometimes up to 1000x

### My Solution

I wrote a stored procedure:

```
 SELECT
   f.*,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [fieldViews] v WHERE v.fieldId = f.fieldId) AS Visible
  FROM [fields] f
  WHERE
   f.X BETWEEN @xFrom AND @xTo AND
   f.Y BETWEEN @yFrom AND @yTo
```

To use this additional column I added the following code:

```
 public partial class Field
  {
   private bool visible = false;
 
   [Column(Storage = "Visible", DbType = "INT")]
   public bool Visible
   {
    get
    {
     return visible;
    }
    set
    {
     visible = value;
    }
   }
  }
```

**This works just fine.**

But ...

#### The Problem

If I fetch entries from Fields table without the stored procedure:

```
from d in DataContext.Fields select d;
```

I got the following error:

> `Bad Storage property: 'Visible' on member 'Models.Field.Visible'.`

So I added the column "Visible" to the database table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Fields ADD
 Visible int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Fields_Visible DEFAULT 0
```

**With this I could solve the error mentioned above.**

But …

#### Next problem

I have fetched some Field objects using the stored procedure.
Now I make some changes to some of these objects.
If I now try to submit these changes it doesn't work. Looking at the generated query unveils the reason:

```
 UPDATE [dbo].[Fields]
 SET [X] = @p3
 WHERE ([FieldId] = @p0) AND ([X] = @p1) AND ([Y] = @p2) AND ([Visible] = 3)
```

The problem here is, that it uses the "Visible" column in the where statement. But the "Visible" column is always 0.
Visible is only greater than 0 if I fetch data using the stored procedure...

### What I need

Something like the ColumnAttribute where the column is not required

or

a way to remove a column from the where statement when updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around which solves my problem:

```
        private bool visible = false;
    public bool Visible
    {
        get
        {
            return visible;
        }
        set
        {
            visible = value;
        }
    }

    private int fakeVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return 0;
        }
        set
        {
            visible = value > 0;
        }
    }

    [Column(Name="Visible", Storage = "fakeVisible", DbType = "Int NOT NULL")]
    public int FakeVisible { get; set; }
```

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

We've solved the original problem  by querying the details table instead, something like:

```
FieldViewsRepository.FieldViews.Where(fv => fv.FieldViewId == Field.FieldID).Count()
```

This generates just one query to the database.

If you need a list of objects with the additional Visible property, you could do something like this:

```
FieldRepository.Fields.Select(f => new { ID=f.FieldID, X=f.X, y=f.Y, Visible=f.FieldViews.Any() }
```

or

```
FieldRepository.Fields.Select(f => new { Field=f, Visible=f.FieldViews.Any() }
```

Unlike the case where Visible is a property on the Filed object and executes the query for each field,  in this case the fields and the Visible property are fetched in one query from th e database.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to store this as a column on the field table - you can calculate this in the Field class:

```
public bool Visible
{
    get { return this.FieldViews.Count() > 0; }
}
```

Comment: Yes this would work. I also used this ... but as I've mentioned: for every field I check this - this would produce 1 query. If I check 1000 fields - it would produce 1000 times this query: SELECT [t0].[FieldViewId], [t0].[FieldId]
FROM [dbo].[FieldViews] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[FieldId] = @p0 ... using the stored procedure is much faster!?